# xsl replace specific character in string

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xls

I am studying XSL and I have question about replacing specific character in string.

we have xml file

```
<family>
-<familyid id="first">
--<name>smith</name>
--<image>fatherpic\myfather.jpg</image>
```

and i would like get image path to insert picture.

For example, we have path "fatherpic\myfather.jpg"

then i would like select "fatherpic/myfather.jpg"

which mean i would like to change"/" to"\".

i was trying to use translate function. but it didn't work.

does any can give example ?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xslt will print replace the '\' with '/' in the image element and will print the rest of the xml file unchanged.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="image">
        <image>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\', '/')" />
        </image>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: can we apply for-each loop?

Comment: what do you want to loop over?

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your post, you could use the translate function.

The following stylesheet extracts the value of the image value and outputs it like text after doing the described string translation. This is just an example of how to use the translate function.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\', '/')" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope it helps.